# Facebook API comments returning 200 error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get comments to work (ideally I just want the total comments per post-id.)

when I input this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/post-id?fields=comments&access_token=XXX
```

I get this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Missing Permissions",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "AEsjATqKyfKbfePVALML5nO"
   }
}
```

Permissions (Page access token):

```
read_insights
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
public_profile
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for after a huge amount of research :)

https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/post-id?fields=insights.metric(post_reactions_by_type_total).period(lifetime).as(post_reactions_by_type_total),comments.summary(true).limit(0),insights.metric(post_clicks_by_type).period(lifetime),shares&access_token=XXX

Cheers all!